# Django and Passenger setup on shared host

Tags: django, passenger, virtualenv, dreamhost

I'm trying to setup Django on a shared hosting provider, Dreamhost. When serving a Django project, Passenger WSGI is used. This works with Dreamhost's default python, but is unable to find the modules in my virtualenv.

I changed my passenger_wsgi.py to include:

```
INTERP = "/home/<username>/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/<venv>/bin/python"
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
```

(as documented on http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Passenger_WSGI)

This breaks the site with a generic Internal Server Error. My Dreamhost log file doesn't provide much additional help: Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html.

How can I configure Passenger to find the Python modules installed in my virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Try add your virtualenv site-packages on your sys.path after you change your INTERP.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/venv/site-packages')
```

this is working with me